# How to connect to data.stackexchange.com through OData

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, data-explorer

This [post](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/06/introducing-stack-exchange-data-explorer/) suggests `data.stackexchange.com` endpoint to connect using `OData` from Linqpad.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom gives `Server Error in '/' Application.`. This seems security flaw, A nice Error Page (like that comes in Stackoverflow.com) would be great, but that is another issue.

In the linqpad, error message is "500 Internal Server Error".

My question is What is the correct URL to connect through OData protocol?

Comment: How is an error page a security flaw?

Comment: OK, it is not flaw.Appropriate Settings are configured (and stacktrace is visible only to local server machines and NOT to remote machines).But Custom error page like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/123) is better.

Comment: Yeah, I agree it's not pretty; it's just not a security issue. And even a stack trace wouldn't be; after all the data explorer [is open source](http://code.google.com/p/stack-exchange-data-explorer/).

Comment: can you tell me the reason why its not working, is it down, or there is some other URL?

Comment: I don't know, the data explorer isn't exactly my area of expertise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When fixing the `odata.stackexchange.com` to `data.stackexchange.com` redirect issue (they're the same site in IIS) it broke the odata bindings because the service model (by default) is unhappy with multiple bindings per site on the same protocol.

I've made the appropriate adjustments and it's back up and running.

Comment: Yes, not it is working. It may be wrong to ask, but can you elaborate the underlying issue that caused "multiple bindings per site on same protocol" to fail

Comment: @Tilak - yeah sure, here's the relevant article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358763.aspx

Comment: This still does not work for me.  I am getting a 404-Not Found error. I am using Linqpad in this case.

Comment: still has a 404 - Not Found error

Comment: @JohnBabb it redirects fine here - what IP are you seeing  for that address?

Comment: @NickCraver if I ping the address:
Pinging data.stackexchange.com [69.59.197.23] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 69.59.197.23: bytes=32 time=97ms TTL=48